# Store password in Bash script and automatically execute

Tags: sql, bash, shell

I have worked on a bash script that automatically visits a directory, executes a file and dumps the file where i want to. Unfortunately, when i execute this file `.sh` file, it asks me for the database password.

Is there anyway we can store the password as a variable and enter it in when it asks. So terminal opens, the program is executed and password is automatically entered and quits.

```
#!/bin/sh
db=databaseName
mamp=location
TS=$(exec date '+%d-%m-%Y')
cd /applications/MAMP/library/bin && \
    ./mysqldump -u root -p $db > "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/$mamp/sql/$db.$TS.sql"
```

Thanks again

Comment: does --password option for mysqldump not fit for want you want?

Comment: I tried the following but it keeps giving me errors: `./mysqldump -u root -password=root $db > "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/$mamp/sql/$db.$TS.sql"`

Comment: Resolved it - `-p'root'`